# PHP nginx server Virtual host redirect error

Tags: php, nginx

When I am use localhost in url then it redirect to my project but when I use myproject.127.0.0.1.xip.io then It shows Server not found error. Below is my code.

Thanks in advance

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name myproject.127.0.0.1.xip.io;
        root /var/www/dev.myproject.com/webroot;
            index index.html index.php;

        # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
        location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
                expires max;
                try_files $uri /index.php; 
        # log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
    client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably the hostname can't be resolved, have you added a

    `127.0.0.1 myproject.127.0.0.1.xip.io`

record to your /etc/hosts file?